# Border around markdown cell in jupyter-notebook - how to remove?

Tags: border, markdown, jupyter-notebook, cell

[image]I noticed when I double click on markdown cell in jyputer-notebook and edit it the border shows up around it. How to make sure markdown cells don't have borders and always have clean background? In the above picture first two markdown cells have borders.

Comment: Can you show us some pics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just re-run the cell that you have edited by selecting the cell and press the run button (or Shift+enter would work)